# Does SCORM really need the flash player to work?

Tags: scorm

I have to do a college project, where I have to do an LMS, and one of the requirements is to allow the import of SCORM files. However, when I went to research I saw something about SCORM using the flash player, which ended support this year. Can anyone answer the question if SCORM really needs the flash player to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only hard technical requirement is a JavaScript environment (or an environment that sufficiently mimics a JavaScript environment) which is why SCORM is very often considered a browser based specification. "Browsers" and therefore JS environments are finding their way into all kinds of places.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit more on Brian's answer, take a look at the following resources.

**SCORM1.2 Golf Examples**

https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=natural_search

**SCORM Run-Time Reference**

https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/

**Rapid E-Learning Dev Software**

```
Articulate
Captivate
Lectora
```

I have experience in all three software's listed above; however, I have standardized all training development in my team to use Lectora because of its flexibility and ability to add JS, jQuery, CSS, etc. to my content. You are really limited by your own skills at that point and if you have the computer programming skills then you can exploit Lectora to it's fullest potential.

Using Lectora, I can use *Actions* to modify any/all SCORM variables using the run-time reference listed above as my guide.